# Application of Karhunen–Loève theorem to Wiener process

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-functions

The [Karhunen-Loève Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosambi%E2%80%93Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20stochastic,Fourier%20series%20representation%20of%20a) is concerned about a continuous second-order process $X=\{X_t, t\in [a,b]\}$, defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$.

The Theorem allows us to apply the following expansion:

$$X_t=\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty Z_ke_k(t), \quad t\in [a,b],$$
where $\{e_k\}$ are the eigenfunctions of the (Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator) linear operator $T_{K_X}:L^2[a,b]\to L^2[a,b]$ and $\{Z_k\}$ are zero mean pairwise orthogonal random variables with corresponding variance $\lambda_k$ (the eigenvalues associated to $e_k$).

**Question** Since $X_t$ is written in terms of basis $\{e_k\}$ of $L^2[a,b]$, is it correct to assume $X_t: (\Omega,\mathcal A,P)\to L^2[0,1]$, that is, $X_t$ is in the (infinite dimensional) family of functions $L^2[0,1]$? What about $X$?

**Comments** In my case, $X=\{X_t, t\in [0,1]\}$ is the Wiener process  defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$ into some infinite dimensional space $F$. I'll apply the Karhunen-Loève expansion for this Wiener process. But I need to make it explict  which set $F$ is.

**Update** It seems that the Karhunen-Loève Theorem works with another point of view: the random functions in $X=\{X_t, t\in[0,1]\}$ are viewed as $X_t\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$ (i.e., the equivalent class of random vables with finite second moment) which is a separable Hilbert space. Hence the stochastic process is given by $[0,1] \to L^2(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ with $t\mapsto X_t$, and not as $\Omega \to F$ with $\omega\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ as I was trying to do before.

Can someone give me directions? I'm not an expert in this field.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the question "what about $X$?" means. The Karhunen-Loeve-Theorem is applicable because for every $t$ we have $E[X_t]=0$ and $X_t\in L^2(\Omega,{\cal A},P)$ and $K_X(s,t)=E[X_sX_t]=\min(s,t)$ is a continuous function in $s,t\,.$ Perhaps you are after the following: the functions $e_k$ are continuous and the convergence of the series is uniform. Therefore both sides of the representation equation are continuous. ...

Comment: Then we can conclude that when that equation holds almost surely for every fixed $t$ it will hold almost surely for all $t\,.$ (Just take $t\in\mathbb Q$ and go from there as usual.)  Conclusion: almost surely we have $X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty Z_k e_k\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I was thinking that the process $X$ could be thought as a function from the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ to a infinite-dimensional space $F$ (some family of functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$). Take, for example, $X$ as the Wiener process on $[0,1]$. As you mentioned, I can apply K-L Theorem because $X_t\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal A,P), \forall t\in[0,1]$. But if $X_t\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal A,P), \forall t\in[0,1]$, which space $F$ could be? I saw some authors working with a subspace $V\subset F$ and calling it as "Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space of $X$".

Comment: @KurtG. Unfortunately, I struggled to understand their concepts. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: The infinite dimensional space that carries the Wiener process is the set of all functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. This space has a Borel $\sigma$-algebra but otherwise it is not very useful. The fact that almost all paths of $W$ are continuous says that effectively the Wiener process lives on $C[0,1]$ which has full Wiener measure in $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}\,.$ I still do not understand why you need the KL-Theorem for all of this. Perhaps it helps to explain what your longer term goals are.

Comment: @KurtG. I´m trying to apply a theorem which holds for a random function $X$ on some probability space and valued in a separable Hilbert space $\mathbb F$.  In my case $X$ is the standard Wiener process on $[0,1]$. I'm wondering if $\mathbb F$ could be $L^2[0,1]$ equipped with the standard inner product.

Comment: @KurtG. Actually, the set $\{e_k\}$ form an orthonormal system in $L^2[0,1]$, but I'm not sure if it forms a basis for the entire $L^2[0,1]$. The K-L says that $X$ can be writen in terms of $\{e_k\}$ with random coefficients $\{Z_k\}$. Does $X$ lives in $L^2[0,1]$ (or in a subspace $span\{e_k\}\subseteq L^2[0,1]$)?